# How to reference CMAttitudeReferenceFrame.CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryCorrectedZVertical from Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I'm trying to use the following method from Swift project with a given reference frame but getting an error "Type '**CMAttitudeReferenceFrame**' has no member '**CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryCorrectedZVertical**'"

```
manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: CoreMotion.CMAttitudeReferenceFrame.CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryCorrectedZVertical, to: .main)
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: CoreMotion.CMAttitudeReferenceFrame.xArbitraryCorrectedZVertical, to: .main)
```

Comment: Most of that is unnecessary in Swift. Module names need only be added in case of symbol name conflicts between local and imported (or multiple imported modules. And enum constants can use implicit member lookup. So the first argument in your call can be just `using: .xArbitraryCorrectedZVertical`.